# What actually happens when we do npm clear cache --force

Tags: angular, npm

I am working on angular and just in general i wanted to know what actually happens in the angular project when we execute command  `npm clear cache --force`  and what type of data is there in cache. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache.html)

> npm stores cache data in an opaque directory within the configured **`cache`**, named **`_cacache`**. This directory is a **`cacache`**-based content-addressable cache that stores all http request data as well as other package-related data. This directory is primarily accessed through **`pacote`**, the library responsible for all package fetching as of npm@5.
>
> All data that passes through the cache is fully verified for integrity on both insertion and extraction. Cache corruption will either trigger an error, or signal to **`pacote`** that the data must be refetched, which it will do automatically. For this reason, **it should never be necessary to clear the cache for any reason other than reclaiming disk space, thus why `clean` now requires `--force` to run.**
>
> There is currently no method exposed through npm to inspect or directly manage the contents of this cache. In order to access it, **`cacache`** must be used directly.
>
> npm will not remove data by itself: the cache will grow as new packages are installed.

To answer your question:

*The cache stores all http request data as well as other package-related data*

Answer (score 3):

The **clear cache** delete all data out of the cache folder and **--force**  "forces" npm to re-download all packages and install them again.

Comment: but can you eleborate like what kind of data is stored? any examples?